# How can i close tag <FormContext.Consumer>?

Tags: typescript, react-component, react-context, react-tsx

[code](https://replit.com/join/zzawpxhw-gebsvasijevs)

I followed the guide from this [site](https://www.carlrippon.com/building-react-form-component-typescript-basics/), but at step 6 there was an error that I cannot fix. I've already tried inserting at the end </FormContext.Consumer> but only more errors appear.

Comment: Your code link does not allow access without an account.

Comment: @DeanJames Iam sorry. New link https://gist.github.com/GlebVasiljev/51278f461d6ede3f1bcb7870c3e61cd0

Comment: Can you share the code for `form.ts`?